# how to pass data from another provider with more than 1 value?

Tags: flutter, flutter-provider

I'm using provider flutter package , but I wanna get the data from another provider and there's an example of doing it using `ChangeNotifierProxyProvider`. But how do I pass more than 1 value in `builder` properties because in the official docs is just using 1 value

```dart
ChangeNotifierProxyProvider<Foo, Bar>(
  initialBuilder: (_) => Bar(),
  builder: (_, foo, bar) => bar
    ..count = foo.count, // I want to pass more than 1 value here...
)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```dart
ChangeNotifierProxyProvider<Foo, Bar>(
  initialBuilder: (_) => Bar(),
  builder: (_, foo, bar) => bar
    ..count = foo.count
    ..something = foo.something,
)
```